# Can we add custom service worker file to flutter web?

Tags: flutter, service-worker, flutter-web

I need to achieve **push notification** in the flutter web app **without using FCM**.

So since flutter has a pre-generated **flutter_service_worker.js** file, can we modify this to achieve push notification or can we add another service worker file?

Please help.

Thanks in advance